# How do I determine why some records within my SharePoint list are read only?

Tags: splistitem, microsoft-access, diagnostics

I'm running a snippet of code to update my `SharePoint List` through `Access 2013`.  It seems that my code works for some records, but other records will give me the

> "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only" warning.

Does anybody have recommendations for diagnosing what is causing some records to be read-only?

Comment: `1.` Check for double-quotes and carriage returns in values that are being inserted for however your logic looks. `2.` Ensure that no one else can open this SAME MS Access DB as this could cause this sort of problem too.  Without knowing further details and exactly how your system is setup, that's a couple quick things to check, test, or eliminate as the cause just in case. Are you importing from SP to the Access DB? Just want to confirm the update is from SharePoint DB to Access and not the other way with some linked source, etc. just in case?

Comment: Hi LMFAO, thanks for your help - to answer your question:  I'm making the update to the sharepoint list with Access:  In access, I linked to a sharepoint list.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I believe so but check #1 and #2 in my comments above to see if that helps any. I don't really have an answer for you so I just left a comment for these things to check initially in case either or these cause the issue. If you're importing FROM the SP list TO the Access DB, then if someone else opens that Access file or already had it opened when you opened it, then that could cause the issue.

Comment: Great to know!  I just swapped computers, so I haven't had a chance to try your recommendation, but when I do, I'll follow up.

Comment: So here's my quick follow-up:  If I remove the double-quotes from my inserted values, I get an error relating to breaking a record's integrity rule.  If I leave the double-quotes, I get the read-only error mentioned above.  Relating to suggestion number 2:  I'm the only one who's currently developing/accessing this database.  Although others could be accessing the sharepoint list item, I doubt anybody is looking at the specific item I'm messing with.  Worth mentioning:  The items within the list in question are generated via SP workflow.  Could this be a problem?